# how to choose best shop using the ranking from database in PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

I want to know how to retrieve the details of the best shop to a table in html page.
The fields of my SQL database are shop_id, shop_name, shop_Tp, shop_addr, shop_sales, shop_rank

Please help me with this.

Please help me to show this result in a table (Tabular format - ID, Name, Telephone, Address, Sales, Ranking)

### My Code

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "osanda92", "test_db");
$mysql="SELECT * FROM shop ORDER BY shop_rank LIMIT 1";
$result=mysqli_query($con,$mysql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo $row['shop_id']."</br>".$row['shop_name']."</br>".$row['shop_Tp']."</br>".$row['shop_addr']."</br>".$row['shop_sales']."</br>".$row['shop_rank']."</br></br></br>";
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: order by shop_rank limit 1 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not 100% clear. But I think you are asking a query to find the best shop. You can write this query to find the best shop.

```
SELECT * FROM YourTableName ORDER BY shop_rank LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Thanks Sasa1234.
I got your query